# F tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc:664] Check failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr Aborted

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, computer-vision, conda

So when running the test.py code from the following repo https://github.com/eldar/pose-tensorflow
I get this error:

```
[jalal@goku pose-tensorflow]$ TF_CUDNN_USE_AUTOTUNE=0 python demo/demo_multiperson.py
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xb
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
2018-04-08 17:09:02.321666: F tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc:664] Check failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr 
Aborted
```

The `test.py` code is:

```
import argparse
import logging
import os

import numpy as np
import scipy.io
import scipy.ndimage

from config import load_config
from dataset.factory import create as create_dataset
from dataset.pose_dataset import Batch
from nnet.predict import setup_pose_prediction, extract_cnn_output, argmax_pose_predict
from util import visualize


def test_net(visualise, cache_scoremaps):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    cfg = load_config()
    dataset = create_dataset(cfg)
    dataset.set_shuffle(False)
    dataset.set_test_mode(True)

    sess, inputs, outputs = setup_pose_prediction(cfg)

    if cache_scoremaps:
        out_dir = cfg.scoremap_dir
        if not os.path.exists(out_dir):
            os.makedirs(out_dir)

    num_images = dataset.num_images
    predictions = np.zeros((num_images,), dtype=np.object)

    for k in range(num_images):
        print('processing image {}/{}'.format(k, num_images-1))

        batch = dataset.next_batch()

        outputs_np = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={inputs: batch[Batch.inputs]})

        scmap, locref, pairwise_diff = extract_cnn_output(outputs_np, cfg)

        pose = argmax_pose_predict(scmap, locref, cfg.stride)

        pose_refscale = np.copy(pose)
        pose_refscale[:, 0:2] /= cfg.global_scale
        predictions[k] = pose_refscale

        if visualise:
            img = np.squeeze(batch[Batch.inputs]).astype('uint8')
            visualize.show_heatmaps(cfg, img, scmap, pose)
            visualize.waitforbuttonpress()

        if cache_scoremaps:
            base = os.path.basename(batch[Batch.data_item].im_path)
            raw_name = os.path.splitext(base)[0]
            out_fn = os.path.join(out_dir, raw_name + '.mat')
            scipy.io.savemat(out_fn, mdict={'scoremaps': scmap.astype('float32')})

            out_fn = os.path.join(out_dir, raw_name + '_locreg' + '.mat')
            if cfg.location_refinement:
                scipy.io.savemat(out_fn, mdict={'locreg_pred': locref.astype('float32')})

    scipy.io.savemat('predictions.mat', mdict={'joints': predictions})

    sess.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--novis', default=False, action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--cache', default=False, action='store_true')
    args, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()

    test_net(not args.novis, args.cache)
```

I have the followings:

```
$ conda list tensorflow
# packages in environment at /scratch/sjn/anaconda:
#
tensorflow                1.5.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-gpu            1.3.0                         0  
tensorflow-gpu-base       1.3.0           py36cuda8.0cudnn6.0_1  
tensorflow-tensorboard    0.1.5                    py36_0
```

and

```
$ conda list numpy
# packages in environment at /scratch/sjn/anaconda:
#
msgpack-numpy             0.4.1                     <pip>
numpy                     1.13.3          py36_blas_openblas_201  [blas_openblas]  conda-forge
numpydoc                  0.7.0            py36h18f165f_0
```

Comment: I suspect this either related to the version of numpy (try updating it, perhaps `conda update numpy` but I'm not sure), or with a possible numpy duplicate in your system. Do you have more than one numpy (or Python) distribution installed?

Comment: thanks @armatita ! in my case I had numpy `v1.14.2` and I did `pip install --upgrade numpy` which put `v1.16.2` and the error is gone. You should post that as an answer